# Cryptographic hash function in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, hash, mapreduce

I need to store some information in a hashed format to anonymize some data in a particular way. I would like to do this using mongodb map reduce but there does not seem to be a way to do this. Is there any way that I could include something like [crypto-js](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) so that my map-reduce functions could use this library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB MapReduce can not load a library from a file. But you could extract the relevant function from [that libraries sourcecode](https://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/src/) and add it to your map- reduce- or finalize function.

When this is a one-time thing it might be a lot easier to write a program for this in a programming language which has a MongoDB driver and provides your chosen algorithm in its standard library.

Comment: fair enough. I think im going to find a different way of doing this then as that sounds not ideal.